# Spring MVC collections from view to controller size 0

Tags: spring-mvc, collections, view, controller

I work with Spring MVC.

I want to pass a whole collection from a view to a controller, but I get size 0 in the controller

First I have the  following controller method in CorreosController where I initialize the collection.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/listadoCorreos", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public ModelAndView listadoCorreos(
            @RequestParam(value = "idEncuesta") String idEncuestaP,
            @RequestParam(value = "pageNumber") String pageNumber,
            @RequestParam(value = "opcion") String opcion,

            HttpServletRequest request, final Model model) throws Exception {

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("/encuesta/actualizarCorreoC");



        List<Encuestado> encuestados = actualizacionesEncuestadoService
                .buscarEncuestadosErroneos(idEncuesta);

   ListaEncuestados correosIncorrectos  = new ListaEncuestados();
    correosIncorrectos.setListaEncuestados(encuestados);

        modelAndView.addObject("listaEncuestados",correosIncorrectos);
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

View actualizarCorreoC.jsp is

```
<form:form
        action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/correos/tablaCorreos"
        name="correos-tabla-correos" id="correos-tabla-correos"  modelAttribute="listaEncuestados"
        method="post" style="margin: 0px;">

        <form:input path="listaEncuestados"   value="${listaEncuestados}"/>

        </form:form>
```

And the following method where I want to get the collection

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/tablaCorreos", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public void  irTablaCorreos(
            @ModelAttribute("listaEncuestados") ArrayList<Encuestado>  encuestadosP,
                        HttpServletRequest request, final Model model) throws Exception {

        logger.info("CorreosController tablaCorreos start");

        logger.info("CorreosController tablaCorreos encuestados size "+encuestadosP.size());


    }
```

In this method a get size 0

Java class ListaEncuestados.java  is

```
package eusurvey.auxiliar;

import java.util.List;

import eusurvey.modelA.daos.Encuestado;

public class ListaEncuestados {
    private List<Encuestado> listaEncuestados;

    public List<Encuestado> getListaEncuestados() {
        return listaEncuestados;
    }

    public void setListaEncuestados(List<Encuestado> listaEncuestados) {
        this.listaEncuestados = listaEncuestados;
    }




}
```

In /correos/tablaCorreos CorreosController the collection size is 0.

How can I pass the whole collection to the controller?

EDITED

```
package eusurvey.modelA.daos;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.math.BigDecimal;


/**
 * The persistent class for the ENCUESTADO database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
public class Encuestado implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "ENCUESTADO_SEQUENCE_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "ENCUESTADO_SEQ",allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ENCUESTADO_SEQUENCE_GENERATOR")
    private long id;

    //private long id;


    @Column(name="ENCUESTA_SEM_ID")
    private long encuestaSemId;

    @Column(name="SURVEY_ID")
    private long surveyId;

    @Column(name="CLA_PENSION")
    private BigDecimal claPension;

    @Column(name="COD_PERSO")
    private BigDecimal codPerso;

    @Column(name="COD_UCP")
    private BigDecimal codUcp;

    @Column(name="CODIGO_POSTAL")
    private BigDecimal codigoPostal;

    @Column(name="COMP_CORREO_ELEC")
    private char compCorreoElec;

    @Column(name="DIR_CORREO_ELEC")
    private String dirCorreoElec;

    private String direccion;

    @Column(name="EMAIL_NO_POSIBLE_ENVIO")
    private String emailNoPosibleEnvio;

    private String emailenviado;

    private String emailenvio;

    @Column(name="ENCUESTADO_UID")
    private String encuestadoUid;

    @Column(name="EXIST_EMAIL")
    private char existEmail;

    @Column(name="FEC_ALTA_NOMINA")
    private String fecAltaNomina;

    @Column(name="FECHA_ENVIO")
    private Timestamp fechaEnvio;

    @Column(name="IND_SEXO")
    private String indSexo;

    @Column(name="INVITATION_ID")
    private BigDecimal invitationId;

    private String localidad;

    @Column(name="NOM_APELLIDO1")
    private String nomApellido1;

    @Column(name="NOM_APELLIDO2")
    private String nomApellido2;

    @Column(name="NOM_NOMBRE")
    private String nomNombre;

    @Column(name="NUM_EXPTE")
    private BigDecimal numExpte;

    private BigDecimal provincia;

    @Column(name="TEL_CONTACTO")
    private String telContacto;

    @Column(name="TIPO_USUARIO")
    private String tipoUsuario;

    @Column(name="COD_PAIS")
    private BigDecimal codPais;

    @javax.persistence.Transient
    private String tipoCorreo;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
      @JoinColumn(name="ENCUESTA_SEM_ID", referencedColumnName="ENCUESTA_SEM_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false),
      @JoinColumn(name="SURVEY_ID", referencedColumnName="SURVEY_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    })
    private EncuestaSem encuestaSem;

    public Encuestado() {
    }



    public long getEncuestaSemId() {
        return encuestaSemId;
    }



    public void setEncuestaSemId(long encuestaSemId) {
        this.encuestaSemId = encuestaSemId;
    }



    public long getSurveyId() {
        return surveyId;
    }



    public void setSurveyId(long surveyId) {
        this.surveyId = surveyId;
    }



    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }



    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }



    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }



    public BigDecimal getClaPension() {
        return this.claPension;
    }

    public void setClaPension(BigDecimal claPension) {
        this.claPension = claPension;
    }

    public BigDecimal getCodPerso() {
        return this.codPerso;
    }

    public void setCodPerso(BigDecimal codPerso) {
        this.codPerso = codPerso;
    }

    public BigDecimal getCodUcp() {
        return this.codUcp;
    }

    public void setCodUcp(BigDecimal codUcp) {
        this.codUcp = codUcp;
    }

    public BigDecimal getCodigoPostal() {
        return this.codigoPostal;
    }

    public void setCodigoPostal(BigDecimal codigoPostal) {
        this.codigoPostal = codigoPostal;
    }

    public char getCompCorreoElec() {
        return this.compCorreoElec;
    }

    public void setCompCorreoElec(char compCorreoElec) {
        this.compCorreoElec = compCorreoElec;
    }

    public String getDirCorreoElec() {
        return this.dirCorreoElec;
    }

    public void setDirCorreoElec(String dirCorreoElec) {
        this.dirCorreoElec = dirCorreoElec;
    }

    public String getDireccion() {
        return this.direccion;
    }

    public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }

    public String getEmailNoPosibleEnvio() {
        return this.emailNoPosibleEnvio;
    }

    public void setEmailNoPosibleEnvio(String emailNoPosibleEnvio) {
        this.emailNoPosibleEnvio = emailNoPosibleEnvio;
    }

    public String getEmailenviado() {
        return this.emailenviado;
    }

    public void setEmailenviado(String emailenviado) {
        this.emailenviado = emailenviado;
    }

    public String getEmailenvio() {
        return this.emailenvio;
    }

    public void setEmailenvio(String emailenvio) {
        this.emailenvio = emailenvio;
    }

    public String getEncuestadoUid() {
        return this.encuestadoUid;
    }

    public void setEncuestadoUid(String encuestadoUid) {
        this.encuestadoUid = encuestadoUid;
    }

    public char getExistEmail() {
        return this.existEmail;
    }

    public void setExistEmail(char existEmail) {
        this.existEmail = existEmail;
    }

    public String getFecAltaNomina() {
        return this.fecAltaNomina;
    }

    public void setFecAltaNomina(String fecAltaNomina) {
        this.fecAltaNomina = fecAltaNomina;
    }

    public Timestamp getFechaEnvio() {
        return this.fechaEnvio;
    }

    public void setFechaEnvio(Timestamp fechaEnvio) {
        this.fechaEnvio = fechaEnvio;
    }

    public String getIndSexo() {
        return this.indSexo;
    }

    public void setIndSexo(String indSexo) {
        this.indSexo = indSexo;
    }

    public BigDecimal getInvitationId() {
        return this.invitationId;
    }

    public void setInvitationId(BigDecimal invitationId) {
        this.invitationId = invitationId;
    }

    public String getLocalidad() {
        return this.localidad;
    }

    public void setLocalidad(String localidad) {
        this.localidad = localidad;
    }

    public String getNomApellido1() {
        return this.nomApellido1;
    }

    public void setNomApellido1(String nomApellido1) {
        this.nomApellido1 = nomApellido1;
    }

    public String getNomApellido2() {
        return this.nomApellido2;
    }

    public void setNomApellido2(String nomApellido2) {
        this.nomApellido2 = nomApellido2;
    }

    public String getNomNombre() {
        return this.nomNombre;
    }

    public void setNomNombre(String nomNombre) {
        this.nomNombre = nomNombre;
    }

    public BigDecimal getNumExpte() {
        return this.numExpte;
    }

    public void setNumExpte(BigDecimal numExpte) {
        this.numExpte = numExpte;
    }

    public  BigDecimal getProvincia() {
        return this.provincia;
    }

    public void setProvincia( BigDecimal provincia) {
        this.provincia = provincia;
    }

    public String getTelContacto() {
        return this.telContacto;
    }

    public void setTelContacto(String telContacto) {
        this.telContacto = telContacto;
    }

    public String getTipoUsuario() {
        return this.tipoUsuario;
    }

    public void setTipoUsuario(String tipoUsuario) {
        this.tipoUsuario = tipoUsuario;
    }



    public BigDecimal getCodPais() {
        return codPais;
    }



    public void setCodPais(BigDecimal codPais) {
        this.codPais = codPais;
    }



    public String getTipoCorreo() {
        return tipoCorreo;
    }



    public void setTipoCorreo(String tipoCorreo) {
        this.tipoCorreo = tipoCorreo;
    }



}
```

Comment: What does `Encuestado` contain? I'm not sure, why are you binding your whole collection to the `<form:input>`.

Comment: I edit my Encuestado class. I don't know how to binding the whole collection to the form:input

Comment: I want to get the whole collection to use in another view